# jQuery checkbox script as facebook invite friends window

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm looking for a jQuery script or idea on how to create a similar window to the one facebook uses when you invite friends to an event.

So basically a dialog window that has a list of people inside and when you select your friends it changes the background color and checks the checkbox of that friend so when they submit the form I can collect the data.

Thanks,

Comment: are you looking for the Modal that Facebook uses?

Comment: would it be ok to use Mootools instead of jQuery?  as a plugin.

Comment: @kjy112 I'm using jQuery for many other functionalities in my website, so I guess it will conflict with Mootools.

Comment: if you are worried about $ conflict then it would not be an issue.  jQuery.noConflict(); would solve that

Comment: @kjy112 Are you sure that will solve all conflicts between Mootools and jQuery? In any case I would rather use jQuery as I don't want to load another framework. But if no one else suggests a solution using jQuery, I would have to go for Mootools given that you know a solution using that framework.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this? Oversimplified, but this should get the point across...

Markup:

```
<div class="member">
     <span class="member_name">Mike</span>
     <input type="checkbox" class="member_checkbox" />
     <input type="hidden" value="002" class="member_id" />
</div>
```

Member Select javascript:

```
// .member-selected would set a new background color
$(".member").click(function() {

     $(this).addClass("member-selected");

     // Find the checkbox
     var checkbox = $(this).find('.member_checkbox');

     // If the checkbox is checked, uncheck it, and
     // if it's not, then check it
     if( $(checkbox).attr("checked") != true) {
          $(checkbox).attr("checked", true);
     } else {
          $(checkbox).attr("checked" false);
     }

});
```

Form submission javascript:

```
// Create an array to hold ID numbers to submit
var add_members = [];

$(".member").each(function() {

     if( $(this).find('.member_checkbox').is(":checked") ) {

          add_members.push( $(this).find('.member_id').val() );

     }
});
```

You would end up with an array of member IDs that you could then post using AJAX.

** EDIT **

In the click function (see above) there should be additional lines that check or uncheck the checkbox based on its current state.

Comment: the jQuery function does not pick up the click when I click on the div. Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: try defining a pretty high z-index on the .member style and see if you have different results.

Comment: Didn't help, I'm pretty sure it's not picking up the click as I am using firebug to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I made a JSBIN out of Mike's suggestion. May help you solve your problem. When a checkbox is clicked its class is alerted then changed (member-selected is added or removed, I'm using toggleClass()) and then its class is alerted again. Check it out: [jsbin.com/uxuxu3/4/edit](http://jsbin.com/uxuxu3/4/edit)

---

I don't know how facebook's 'invite friends to an event' window looks these days, but I believe you will find Facebox a similar modal. Check Facebox and other, perhaps even better options, at [19 jQuery Modal Boxes to improve your UI](http://coderplus.com/2009/11/jquery-modal-boxes-to-improve-your-ui/).

Comment: Saw this while looking for solutions on google. doesn't help as this is not a styling issue but more of a functionality question.

Comment: I made a JSBIN out of Mike's suggestion. May help you solve your problem. When a checkbox is clicked its class is alerted then changed (member-selected is added or removed, I'm using toggleClass()) and then its class is alerted again. Check it out: http://jsbin.com/uxuxu3/4/edit